# Excel 2010 Reference table data from one sheet to other

Tags: excel, csv

I prepared `Data` sheet that contains my primary database

```
    A          B          C
1   ID         Col2       Col3
2   800         90        120
3   799         50        110
4   798         80        785
5   797         60        642
6   796         60        212
7   795         26        163
8   794         66        171
9   793         36        673
10  792         16        223
11  791         31        133
12  790         83        253
13  789         33        256
14  788         31        623
```

I now want to create 3 more sheets named `TakeAll`, `TakeEvery2nd`, `TakeEvery4th`

**What I am trying to do:**

`Take All` - will take all the data from `Data` sheet and will display it as the original:

```
    A          B          C
1   ID         Col2       Col3
2   800         90        120
3   799         50        110
4   798         80        785
5   797         60        642
6   796         60        212
7   795         26        163
8   794         66        171
9   793         36        673
10  792         16        223
11  791         31        133
12  790         83        253
13  789         33        256
14  788         31        623
```

`Take Every 2nd` - will take every second row, meaning will take the 1st Id which is `800` and will than skip every 2nd (will show Id's `800, 798, 796, 794, 792, 790`)
and will look like this:

```
    A          B          C
1   ID         Col2       Col3
2   800         90        120
4   798         80        785
6   796         60        212
8   794         66        171
10  792         16        223
12  790         83        253
14  788         31        623
```

`Take Every 4th`- will take the first row and will take every 4th meaning:

```
    A          B          C
1   ID         Col2       Col3
2   800         90        120
6   796         60        212
10  792         16        223
14  788         31        623
```

**Note:**

```
`Data` will be modified and also new rows are planned to be added
```

I am having difficulties to understand how to approach it

Comment: How many rows? A filter with a helper column using the [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-0CAF2C6C-891D-4A0B-B618-3B0D60296809) would be faster for many rows.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, using the [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-0CAF2C6C-891D-4A0B-B618-3B0D60296809) in a 'helper' column to sequence the staggers seems a good choice.

```
Sub break_many()
    Dim rw As Long, v As Long, vMODs As Variant, vWSs As Variant

    vMODs = Array(1, 2, 4)
    vWSs = Array("TakeAll", "TakeEvery2nd", "TakeEvery4th")

    With Sheets("Sheet4")   '<-set this worksheet reference!
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        For v = LBound(vMODs) To UBound(vMODs)
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                With .Offset(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                    .Formula = "=MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, " & vMODs(v) & ")"
                End With
            End With
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                .AutoFilter field:=.Columns.Count, Criteria1:=0
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1)
                    .Copy Destination:=Sheets(vWSs(v)).Cells(1, 1)
                End With
                .AutoFilter field:=.Columns.Count
                With .Offset(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                    .Clear
                End With
            End With
        Next v
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

That does depend upon the three target worksheets already existing and does not clear the target before pasting the data.